# Moving Reports in Salesforce using Force.com IDE

Tags: ide, salesforce

I'm trying to mass move reports to different folders in salesforce using the Force.com IDE.

I've followed the instructions provided by SarathPM here:
http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000IEOSEA4

I update my package.xml, move the corresponding files and then try to save to server. 
However, I keep getting the following errors:

When deploying:
**Save error: DeveloperName: This Report Unique Name already exists or has been previously used.  Please choose a different name.**

When saving to server:
**Unable to save resource 'All_Leads.report' to server: IllegalArgumentException: Project and/or project package list cannot be null.**

There must be a way to move reports in salesforce other than manually saving each report to a different folder. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I did a fresh checkout of the reports folder only.

**package.xml before**

```
<members>SampleConsultingDashboardReports</members>
<members>SampleConsultingDashboardReports/AvgEngagementLengthByPracticeArea</members
<members>Utility_Reports</members>
<members>Utility_Reports/X10_reports_Account_activities_last_7d</members>
```

**package.xml after**

```
<members>SampleConsultingDashboardReports</members>
<members>Utility_Reports</members>
<members>Utility_Reports/AvgEngagementLengthByPracticeArea</members>
<members>Utility_Reports/X10_reports_Account_activities_last_7d</members>
```

Save package.xml, move AvgEngagementLengthByPracticeArea.report to Utility_Reports. Refresh in Eclipse, I see the changes. I try to "Save to Server" and it tells me the "Project is not synchronized with the associated Salesforce organization." I bypass the message and try to save anyway, which is when the "Unable to save resource 'Utility Reports' to server" message shows up.

I tried Synchronizing everything with the server before making any changes. Still get the same error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that the method described by Sarath, when followed exactly, works. You'll need a more specific repro scenario. I'd suggest trying to move just a single report. Just to be clear, the steps are:

- download a fresh copy of your reports metadata via Eclipse
- manually edit the package.xml to change the folder of a report. (I think you need to make sure the folder exists on the server, and that you are referring to the developer name of it, e.g. Folder_A/My_report)
- in the underlying file system, move that report to a folder of that name
- in Eclipse, do a project refresh from the local file system (NOT the server)
- in Eclipse, do a save to server
- the report should move

If this also does not work, post your package.xml before and after, and the exact steps you followed.

Comment: That's strange because I upvote almost every answer I receive. Is that the equivalent of an accept? Will post package.xml shortly.

Comment: That explains it :) Accepting is a special action (exposed as the big green check mark underneath the voting buttons) that only the asker can do. Upvoting means "good answer", accepting means "THE correct answer for my question."